# IsTrial always returns false

Tags: windows-phone-8, marketplace

When I check if my Windows Phone 8 app is trial, the following code always returns false, even on the device

```
Microsoft.Phone.Marketplace.LicenseInformation license = new Microsoft.Phone.Marketplace.LicenseInformation();
license.IsTrial();
```

As far as I understand, the IsTrial will return false only on debug mode and on emulator.

In my case that code returns false even on a physical device with the release bits. Is this expected?

PS: the application is not yet published.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is expected - in debiug mode or if your App is not published you will get false.
As it is said on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286402%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Checkingforatriallicenseinyourapp):

```
Real license information is available for an app only after it has been 
published to the Store.
```

If your App is working fine with license = true/false then after publishing App the code you have preseted should work. The best practise is to put that code in Application_Launching and Activatied events.
Note also that beta version is always free - so you also get false.